# How to make offline a site in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have added a param in config/main.php to determine if the site is offline or not. I've tried

```
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
if(!Yii::app()->params['enabled'])
  die;
```

at the bottom of index.php file. but it doesn't die. Why?

Comment: i think if you call the `DIE` at the end, it is too late, as the `->run()` command already called the APP to run..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use CWebApplication::CatchAllRequest in your config

Refer : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#catchAllRequest-detail

You can specify a controller/route to show a maintenance page by changing your config array; You can have different config file for when the site is down for maintenance; and another one for when it is live 
your config file should look something like

```
return array(
 .... 
     'catchAllRequest'=>array(
          'offline/notice'
          'otherParams'=>'value',
      ),
 ....
),
```

You of course need to have an offline controller and notice action plus a notice view file;